# Asp.NET. How to validate <asp:TextBox> control on a client side before submitting to server?

Tags: asp.net, validation, client-side, server-side

I have the following code on my asp.net page:

```
<table>
<tr>    
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegions" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> 
</td>
<td>
    <label>Enter Iso:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtIso" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfIso" runat="server" />
</td>
<td>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActiveEmail" runat="server" Text="Email On/Off"/>
</td>
<td><asp:Button ID="btnAddActivation" Text="Add New Validation" OnCommand="AddNewActivation" runat="server"/></td>
</tr>     
</table>
```

I need to validate my `textbox` txtIso when my `btnAddActivation` button clicked and then I will need to proceed to the code-behind>

With simple html form I could use `onsubmit = return Function()`. How can I do it now?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Custom javascript**

If you want to use custom javascript you can use the onclientclick:

```
 onclientclick="YourJSFunction()"
```

The server side code will execute when you return true.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddActivation" Text="Add New Validation" onclientclick="YouJSFunction()" OnCommand="AddNewActivation" runat="server"/>
```

See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

There are also built in validation controls that you could use for regular expression and required fields i.e.

**RegularExpressionValidator**

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtIso" runat="server"  ValidationExpression="String" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx

**RequiredFieldValidator**

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
      ControlToValidate="txtIso"
      Text="Required Field!" 
      runat="server"/>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out [validation controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
By default they have client-side validation enabled, so you don't need to write js code.

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIso" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtIsoValidator" ControlToValidate="txtIso" ErrorMessage="Please enter a value." Text="*" runat="server"/>
```